# I'm getting a failed to load resource for an multiple angular app load on an html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my js I added the variables. Normally I can just pull data out of the array no matter how many I add.

```
var gvmItems = angular.module('gvmItems', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['gvmItems', 'gvm2Items']);

gvmItems.controller('gvmItemController', function($scope) {
$scope.gvmItems = [
{
    id: 10,
    title: 'Robe King - GVM',
    data: 'gvm-main',
    link: 'http://galnova.com/ultra/2020/Robe-King-GVM.png',
    thumb: 'http://galnova.com/ultra/2020/Robe-King-GVM-3.png',
    name: 'Crin Robinson',
    nickname: 'The Robe King',
    house: 'Robe',
    age: '36',
    job: 'Robe Lord',
    style: 'Hope Bringer',
    type: 'Noble',
    anid: 'robekingInfo',
    nameshort: 'Crin',
    story: 'King of Lords (The most powerful nation as the story begins). Crin has Final Boss level strength and a strong sense of justice.',
    datasrc: '#robekingInfo',
    weaponname: 'Star Dusk',
    weapon: 'http://galnova.com/ultra/2020/crin-weapon.png',
    data2: 'gvm-main2',
    }
}];

    $scope.gvm2Items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'The Wolf King - Lem',
        year: '2020',
        type: 'ink',
        img: 'http://galnova.com/A20/ink-20/1.PNG',
        program: 'Procreate',
        desc: 'Galaxy Inks @galnova'
        }
    ];
        
    });
```

In the HTML I made sure to call the object like usual.

```
<html ng-app="gvmItems">
```

Then on the page

The first one works fine and loads. No issues.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 flx mast_wrap" ng-repeat="gvmItem in gvmItems">
  <div class="panel_wrap nill flx">
  <div class="row nill">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <a title="{{ gvmItem.title }}" class="fancybox un zero" data-fancybox="{{ gvmItem.data }}" data-caption="{{ gvmItem.datacap }}" href="{{ gvmItem.link }}">
    <img class="nill" alt="{{ gvmItem.title }}" src="{{ gvmItem.thumb }}">
    </a>
   </div>
      
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 small_nill">
     <div class="hd">{{ gvmItem.name }}</div>
          <p class="">"{{ gvmItem.nickname }}"</p>
          <ul class="flex_el">
              <li>House: {{ gvmItem.house }}</li> 
              <li>Age: {{ gvmItem.age }}</li>
              <li>Job: {{ gvmItem.job }}</li>
              <li>Style: {{ gvmItem.style }}</li>
              <li>Type: {{ gvmItem.type }}</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div style="display: none;" id="{{ gvmItem.anid }}" class="animated-modal">
          <img src="{{ gvmItem.thumb }}" />
          <h3>{{ gvmItem.nameshort }}</h3>
          <p>{{ gvmItem.story }}</p>
      </div>
        <div class="bttn_wrapper">
          <a data-fancybox data-animation-duration="700" data-src="{{ gvmItem.datasrc }}" href="javascript:;"><button type="button" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 float-left btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span class="fa fa-info-circle"></span> More about {{ gvmItem.moreabout }}</button></a>
           <a title="{{ gvmItem.weapondata }}" class="fancybox zero" data-fancybox="gvm-main2" data-caption="{{ gvmItem.nickname }} - {{ gvmItem.weaponname }}" href="{{ gvmItem.weapon }}"><button type="button" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 float-right btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg"><span class="fa fa-bomb"></span> {{ gvmItem.weaponname }}</button></a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the second one doesn't load at all. It's giving me the failed to load resources error.

```
  <div class="itm item col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 grip_wrap gonzo" ng-repeat="gvm2Item in gvm2Items">
    <div class="grip_hang_topp"></div>
        <div class="col grip">
          <h3>{{ gvm2Item.name }}</h3>
            <a title="{{ gvm2Item.desc }}" class="fancybox zero" data-fancybox="gallery1" data-caption="{{ gvm2Item.desc }}" href="{{ gvm2Item.img }}">
            <img alt="{{ gvm2Item.desc }}" src="{{ gvm2Item.img }}" />
            </a>
          <div class="col coat2 truncate bleww">{{ gvm2Item.desc }}</div>
        </div>
    <div class="grip_hang_bott"></div>
    </div>
```

It's strange because I used a similar structure on another page and it let me pull data out of different arrays with ease. It did not break!

http://galnova.com/portfolio/

Please help! I do not know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the second gvmItemController for the wrapper on the html

```
<div id="gl" ng-controller="gvmItemController" class="container-fluid tab-pane">
```

Maybe this will help someone else